# Google Maps getting kml from fusiontable and display them

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to build something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test//v3_FusionTables_CountryBrowser_encryptedID.html) for the Netherlands. I have the name of the provinces and you click one of it and that should loud the borders of it and display it, so set the right bounds. Here is my code:

```
var FT_TableID = "19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA";
var CountryName = "Netherlands";
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.24730, 5.36449),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

  jQuery("span").click(function() {
    var name = jQuery(this).text();
    //map.fitBounds(gpolygons[id].bounds);
    var queryStr = {
      select: 'kml_4326',
      from: FT_TableID,
      where: "'name_0' = '" + CountryName + "' AND 'name_1' = '" + name + "'"
    };
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryStr);
    var FT_Options = {
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      query: query
    };
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(FT_TableID, FT_Options);
    layer.setMap(map);
  });

});
```

A working example is also on codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXvXjb

My problem: It displays the borders and kml data of everything in the view port, not only the selected province. Is something with the query wrong? Also I want that like in the example of geocodezip, the view port is set to the selected province. For this I need the boundsdata and set it with  `bounds.extend()` and `map.fitBounds(bounds)`. But where can I get this data from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [FusionTableLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer) isn't working the way you expect because you are using the wrong syntax (the "old" syntax, not the [currently documented](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#FusionTablesLayer) syntax).  The "old" syntax doesn't work with encrypted ids.  When the query syntax is incorrect, but you give it a valid table, it displays all the data.

The "old" syntax:

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(FT_TableID, FT_Options);
```

This is the (currently) documented syntax:

```
var FT_Options = {
  suppressInfoWindows: true,
  query: {
    select: 'kml_4326',
    from: FT_TableID,
    where: "'name_0' = '" + CountryName + "'"
  },
  styles: [{
    polygonOptions: {
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeWeight: 3
    }
  }]
};
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(FT_Options);
```

You also have issues with your province queries (you have the province names spelled wrong (or at least differently from those in the table), so the queries don't match any rows.

**code snippet:**

```js
var FT_TableID = "19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA";
var CountryName = "Netherlands";
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.24730, 5.36449),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  var queryStr = {
    select: 'kml_4326',
    from: FT_TableID,
    where: "'name_0' = '" + CountryName + "'"
  };
  var FT_Options = {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    query: queryStr,
    styles: [{
      polygonOptions: {
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeWeight: 3
      }
    }]
  };
  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(FT_Options);
  layer.setMap(map);
  jQuery("span").click(function() {
    var name = jQuery(this).text();
    var queryStr = {
      select: 'kml_4326',
      from: FT_TableID,
      where: "'name_0' = '" + CountryName + "' AND 'name_1' = '" + name + "'"
    };
    var FT_Options = {
      query: queryStr,
      styles: [{
        polygonOptions: {
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
          strokeWeight: 3
        }
      }]
    };
    layer.setOptions(FT_Options);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Zeeland</span>
<span>Drenthe</span>
<br>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```